# CSS3 Transitions not working on iOS Safari

Tags: html, ios, css, web, safari

For some reason, my CSS3 Transitions are working on every browser except for on Safari (tested on iOS). I believe I've done everything right, but it's just not working.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/KingKundi/pen/RgMmJp

HTML:

```css
 /*
    ==========================
    Universal
    ==========================
    */
    
    * {
      font-family: "Heebo";
    }
    
    h1 {
      font-size: 4rem;
      color: #4d4d4d;
    }
    
    h4 {
      font-size: 2rem;
      color: #0072ff;
    }
    
    h2 {
      font-size: 2.5rem;
      color: #0072ff;
      padding: 2rem 2rem;
    }
    
    p {
      line-height: 2rem;
      padding: 0 2rem;
      font-size: 1.3rem;
      color: #4d4d4d;
    }
    
    a {
      outline: none;
    }
    
    .center {
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
    
    .center-text {
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .center-v {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
    }
    
    /*
    ==========================
    Home
    ==========================
    */
    
    .hero {
      background-color: #ffffff;
    }
    
    .intro {
      padding-top: 5rem;
    }
    
    .img-circle {
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
    
    .hero-link {
      color: #000000;
      font-size: 3rem;
    }
    
    .fa {
      font-size: 5.5rem;
      padding: 0.5rem 2rem;
      color: #4d4d4d;
    }
    
    .fa:focus {
      color: #4d4d4d;
    }
    
    .fa:hover {
      color: #0072ff;
    }
    
    .fa-home {
        font-size: 3rem;
        position: fixed;
    }
    
    .fa-project {
        color: #ffffff;
        z-index: 11;
      font-size: 4rem;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
    }
    
    /*
    ==========================
    Project tiles
    ==========================
    */
    
    @media (max-width: 1000px) {
      #project-break {
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: 0;
      }
    }
    
    .tile {
      height: 27rem;
      width: 100%;
      margin:10px;
      display:inline-block;
      background-size:cover;
      position:relative;
      cursor:pointer;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
      -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
      -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
      -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
      transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
      box-shadow: 0px 35px 77px -17px rgba(0,0,0,0.44);
      overflow:hidden;
      color:white;
    }
    
    .tile img {
      height:100%;
      width:100%;
      position:absolute;
      top:0;
      left:0;
      z-index:0;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
      -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
      -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
      -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
      transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
    }
    
    .tile .text {
        z-index: 11;
      position:absolute;
      padding:30px;
      height:calc(100% - 60px);
    }
    
    .tile h1 {
        color: #ffffff;
      font-size: 1.75rem;
      font-weight:300;
      text-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    }
    
    .tile p {
        color: #ffffff;
      font-weight: 300;
      margin: 20px 0 0 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-200px);
        -o-transform: translateX(-200px);
        -moz-transform: translateX(-200px);
        -ms-transform: translateX(-200px);
      transform: translateX(-200px);
      transition-delay: 0.2s;
    }
    
    .animate-text {
      opacity:0;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
      -ms-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
      transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
    }
    
    .tile:hover {
      box-shadow: 0px 35px 77px -17px rgba(0,0,0,0.64);
      -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
      -o-transform: scale(1.05);
      -moz-transform: scale(1.05);
      -ms-transform: scale(1.05);
      transform: scale(1.05);
    }
    
    .tile:hover img {
      opacity: 0.2;
    }
    
    .tile:hover .animate-text {
      -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
      -o-transform: translateX(0);
      -moz-transform: translateX(0);
      -ms-transform: translateX(0);
      transform: translateX(0);
      opacity:1;
    }
    
    /*
    .tile:hover span {
      opacity:1;
      transform:translateY(0px);
        -webkit-transform:translateY(0px);
        -o-transform:translateY(0px);
        -moz-transform:translateY(0px);
        -ms-transform:translateY(0px);
    }
    */
    
    @media (max-width: 550px) {
        .tile p {
            font-size: 1.1rem;
            line-height: 1.5rem;
        }
    }
    
    @media (max-width: 320px) {
        .tile p {
            font-size: 0.9rem;
            line-height: 1.5rem;
        }
    }
    
    .fa-fade {
        -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
        transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    }
    
    .pomodoro {
      background-image: url("assets/pomodoro-site.png");
        background-position: center;
    }
    
    .duelr {
      background-image: url("assets/duelr-site.png");
        background-position: center;
    }
    
    .grt-bot {
      background-image: url("assets/grt-site.png");
        background-position: center;
    }
    
    .pomodoro:after,
    .duelr:after,
    .grt-bot:after {
      content: " ";
      z-index: 10;
      position: absolute;
      height: 100%;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    }
    
    p > a {
        color: #ffffff;
    }
    
    p > a:hover {
        color: #0072ff;
    }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/7743338bf9.js"></script>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Heebo" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/normalize.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/skeleton.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/main.css">
      <link rel="icon" href="static/assets/favicon.png">
    </head>
    
    <body>
      <div class="hero center-text">
        <div class="container">
          <section class="intro twelve columns">
          <div class="row">
            <h2>projects</h2>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="one-half column" id="project-break">
                <div class="tile u-max-full-width pomodoro">
                  <div class="text center-text">
                    <h1>Pomodoro</h1>
                    <p class="animate-text">
                      Pomodoro is a productivity oriented web application which incentivizes the<br><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pomodoro_Technique" target="_blank">Pomodoro Technique</a>.
                    </p>
                    <p class="animate-text">
                      Built with: Django/Python, HTML5, CSS, JavaScript, jQuery, and AJAX.
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-github fa-project animate-text fa-fade" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="one-half column" id="project-break">
                <div class="tile u-max-full-width duelr">
                  <div class="text center-text">
                    <h1>Duelr</h1>
                    <p class="animate-text">
                      An online multiplayer 1v1 fighting game.
                    </p>
                    <p class="animate-text">
                      Built with: JavaScript, Node.js, Express.js, Socket.io, HTML5, CSS, and Phaser.
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-github fa-project animate-text fa-fade" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="twelve columns">
                <div class="tile u-max-full-width center grt-bot">
                  <div class="text center-text">
                    <h1>GRT Messenger Bot</h1>
                    <p class="animate-text">
                      The Grand River Transit Bot is a service published on Facebook Messenger which yields real-time bus information to users through HTTP requests.
                    </p>
                    <p class="animate-text">
                      Built with: JavaScript, Node.js, Express.js, and API.ai.
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-github fa-project animate-text fa-fade" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <h2>contact</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <script src="static/app.js"></script>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: What happens if you break  the transition into it's constituent parts: `-webkit-transition-property, -webkit-transition-duration, -webkit-timing-function` etc?

Comment: @BrianPeacock Now it's working on CodePen but not on my domain - www.allanmukundi.com

Comment: Browsers are weird sometimes but your code looks solid - I can only assume its an Safari implementation failure or a device OS issue. Perhaps a graceful fallback is the best you can expect here?

Comment: @BrianPeacock maybe it's my use of hover?

Answer (score 0):

I've run into a similar issue where targeting both a parent and a child with the same animation fails (only happens on mobile safari iOS 12).

I fixed it by targeting the elements more precisely.

Something like:

```
div * {
  transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
}

<div>
  <span>Works just fine</span>
  <p>Also works</p>
  <ul>
    <li>Fail</li>
    <li>Fail</li>
    <li>Fail</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Can be fixed by:

```
div > * {
  transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
}
```